# In C#, is there a way to "choose" a type by a string/variable?

Tags: c#, types, umbraco, .net-assembly

I'm mapping what will soon be about 30-40 different blocks coming from a CMS by way of JSON which indeed comes with the alias of the block type. Is there a way I can use the alias thats coming through as a string to then directly select the C# type/model in my code?

Currently I'm matching them up like this.

```
switch (block.Type)
{
  case "Heading":
    mapped = _umbracoMapper.Map<Heading>(block);
    break;
  case "Carousel":
    mapped = _umbracoMapper.Map<Carousel>(block);
    break;
  case "Alert":
    mapped = _umbracoMapper.Map<Alert>(block);
    break;
  case "Text":
    mapped = _umbracoMapper.Map<Text>(block);
    break;
  default:
  break;
}
```

I understand that the Type isn't really words/letters but is there any way I can reference type to tidy up this repetition, something like..

```
mapped = _umbracoMapper.Map<[block.Type]>(block);
```

I'm not 100% sure the above is possible in C#, but I attempted a few versions of the following but its returning **System.Type** as opposed to (in this case) **Blocks.Models.Heading** as the mappers **Map** method requires it to have the target type to be passed to it so it can decipher from which and to what it needs to map. I cant pass it object, dynamic or System.Type, it needs to be the exact type (Heading, Carousel, Alert, Text etc.)

```
_umbracoMapper.Map(block, Type.GetType("Blocks.Models." + block.Type + ", Blocks"));
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You seem to be looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method

Comment: Why do you append ", Blocks" the the `GetType()` call? Without this, it should work. Reflection is possible too, but can be slow and is not type safe, so I'd avoid it when working with external data.

Comment: Have you thought about Hash tables or maybe a dictionary?, i mean you can perform this calculation once and after that just accessing by the `string`?  content

Comment: @PMF This solution has multiple projects, and although indeed this file is in the **Blocks** project, without that being appended the Type returns back as null.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost on the correct side. You can use reflection to dynamically create a generic method based on the string value of the block type.

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Blocks.Models." + block.Type + ", Blocks");
MethodInfo method = typeof(UmbracoMapper).GetMethod("Map");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
mapped = generic.Invoke(_umbracoMapper, new object[] { block });
```

This code uses the Type.GetType method to get the Type object for the specified type name then gets the Map method from the UmbracoMapper class, creates a generic method with the specified type using the MakeGenericMethod method, and finally invokes the generic method with the specified arguments using the Invoke method.

Comment: The above is great, but I run into trouble at `typeof(UmbracoMapper).GetMethod("Map")` with it complaining a lack of ambiguity as I need to have passed it the target type for it to decipher with Map method to use.

Comment: @WNTR In that case, use `GetMethods()` instead (which returns an array of overloads) and then choose the right one by looking at the number of parameters.